# restrict git command on git client

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

I would like to check if there is way to restrict git clone of a repo for users and sametime repo files should be viewed from STASH itself so that the user don't get the repo files physically downloaded into local machine.

Comment: You want the user to be able to *see* the content of the file, but not to be able to download/clone it?  What is the use-case?

Comment: yes, user should be able to browse centralised repo from web only. Atlassian STASH Repo read access provides the ability to access the repo from web and includes access to clone it to their local machine, i would like to restrict the clone part.

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether or not you have access/control to the remote server.

As Junio C Hamano mentioned in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Can-I-prevent-someone-clone-my-git-repository-td2126694.html)

> If they come over the http transport, you would solve it the same way as
>   you solve "how do I allow access to these files on my webserver to only
>   selected few?"  Probably `.htaccess` file in the toplevel directory will be
>   involved.